# How can I use Visual Studio designer without form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio to create a Windows Form project.

There are no Form classes in the Solution Explorer for my project - I build all my forms on the fly. So I have no opportunity to open the Designer in Visual Studio, or the Toolbox.

But I want to create a ContextMenuStrip and edit it in the Designer. I normally do this by dragging a ContextMenuStrip from the ToolBox onto the Designer.  However, I don't have any way (that I can tell) to open the Designer without first creating a form, or user control.

How can I edit a ContextMenuStrip in the designer without first associating it with a form or user control?

To be clear - I know how to generate a ContextMenuStrip on the fly, in code. That is not what I want. I want to use the Designer to create and edit a ContextMenuStrip, without having to first associate the ContextMenuStrip with a form or user control that I'm not going to include in my project.

(Visual Studio 2013 Pro, if that matters)

Comment: I am not quite sure what you meant - but perhaps the [property grid control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx) will do what you want

Comment: You can't, you need a form or a usercontrol.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - so... I create a user control in VS and add a context menu to that control in the designer, and edit it; then in my "build form on fly" code, I instantiate the user control, do NOT add the user control to the form, and then set the form.ContextMenuStrip to myUserControl.ContextMenuStrip?

Comment: I cannot say whether that will work or not, all I can say is that the designer in Visual Studio is not designed to design standalone controls or components, it is designed to design forms and usercontrols. Whether your usage of the contextmenustrip from the usercontrol that you don't add to your form will work or not I cannot tell you, you will just have to experiment.

Comment: @GrantWinney - the forms are windows I create on the fly with a single user control on them - a drawing surface. That is why they don't exist as pre-made classes.  Meanwhile - separately - the ContextMenuStrip is part of a Decorator class that various consumers add to the drawing control, to give it different functionality at different times.  The Decorator class has no user controls in it, so there's no ability to provide the ContextMenuStrip as anything but run-time code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible, and I don't think it really makes sense under scrutiny.

The Designer is a tool for helping you build forms and user controls. That's it really. It saves you writing code to create and plot controls manually. It provides shortcuts and a nice graphical view of what is essentially automatic code generation.

What you're trying to create is neither a new `UserControl` type, nor is a new `Form` type - either of which can be created in the Designer. It's a menu strip with certain things pre-added to it. This cannot exist in isolation. It needs to translate to code which creates and adds members to a concrete `ContextMenuStrip` object. That object has to live in a class somewhere (`Form` or `UserControl`). I don't see how it could exist on its own.

Comment: "I don't think this makes sense under scrutiny."  -- It doesn't make sense to wonder if the Designer I am offered is capable of helping me graphically edit a known datastructure that I am declaring in code?  I can see why the builders would choose not to support this, but I hardly think the desire "doesn't make sense".  I see that the question is also being downvoted, and this is also beyond me.  If it is a question that more than one VS user might ask, how is that not useful on Stackoverflow?  Ah well.  The mysteries of what Stackoveflow is becoming continue.

Comment: I think it's a very reasonable question - I upvoted it, in fact. By 'doesn't make sense' I mean 'doesn't fit with the way the designer is intended to work'. Apologies if my answered seemed in any way offensive.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem... new solution...

1. create a UserControl (eg. UC1)
2. Add the ContextMenu to UC1 as CC1 and design/edit it there
3. Add the UserControl to your project (or create by code)
4. refer to UC1.CC1 for your now '''very usable'' ContextMenu

Comment: Should work, but you'd have to change the modifiers property of CC1 to public to be able to see it...

Answer (score 0):

You could add your ContextMenuStrip to a Form, then modify the form with code so that you access it with a singleton type property:

```
public partial class frmContextMenuHost : Form
{

    private frmContextMenuHost()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static frmContextMenuHost _frmContextMenu = null;

    public static ContextMenuStrip GetContextMenu
    {
        get
        {
            if (_frmContextMenu == null)
            {
                _frmContextMenu = new frmContextMenuHost();
            }
            return _frmContextMenu.contextMenuStrip1;
        }
    }

}
```

How are you planning on using the events for the ContextMenuStrip?